# How to decide what concurrency to use for Celery in a two core machine (for API Requests & DB Queries bound)

Tags: python, celery

I have a few Celery workers that perform tasks that are not always that fast. The tasks are usually a bunch of HTTP requests and DB queries (using pyscopg2 behind SQLAlchemy). I'm running in Kubernetes and the CPU usage is always fairly low (0.01 or so). Celery automatically set the concurrency to 2 (number of cores of a single node), but I was wondering whether it would make sense to manually increase this number.

I always read that the concurrency (processes?) should be the same as the number of cores, but if the worker does not use a whole core, couldn't it be more? Like `concurrency=10` ? Or that would make no difference and I'm just missing the point of processes and concurrency?

I couldn't find information on that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is true. Celery automatically sets the number of cores as concurrency, as it assumes that you will the entire core (CPU intensive task).
Sounds like you can increase the concurrency, as your tasks are doing more I/O bound tasks (and the CPU is idle).

To be on the safe side, I would do it gradually and increase to 5 first, monitor, ensure that CPU are fine and then to 10..

Comment: Makes sense, that's what's lacking in Celery's docs, the assumption that my task uses a full core. I'm discovering that is not that simple of a change, since I start to get loads of errors in SQLAlchemy, I imagine I have to correctly configure the Connection Pool for the workers, still have to figure this out. But from your answer, I understand that I should probably try to increase the concurrency, which will increase the number of process running (number of tasks a worker can run in parallel), while keeping memory low (only using 1 worker, instead of memory * no of workers).

Comment: BTW, would you have any recommendation on the "pool" configuration as well?

Comment: You asked about CPU and not about memory. I guess that the memory will increase as well (corellate to concurrency level) so just increase it gradually and monitor it.

Comment: Maybe you can use worker_init signal for that (I didn't try) https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/signals.html#worker-init